# Key Strokes Encrpytion

Tags: python, keystroke, keylogger

I want to encrypt key strokes using python (similar to a KeyScrambler program feature), so any keylogger would not be able to record any human-readable key strokes. Please, any help?

Comment: you should add more details, like do you want to capture the keystroke and save it in some encrypted format in done file or what. and secondly, you should add details like, what you tried and where are you stucking.

Comment: No, I do not want to save them in encrypted format. I want them to be encrypted when a keylogger hooks any keyboard events.